# Why does amazon-aws-jdk 1.11.95 returns File not found exception while uploading image to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload an image to AWS S3.

The web app runs in my local desktop in tomcat server. 
When I upload the image from server, I see the file details in http request multipart file , I'm able to get its size and details.

This is how I set up connection

```
 File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename());
            file.transferTo(convFile);  

 AmazonS3 s3 =   AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2) //regionName is a string for a region not supported by the SDK yet
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
                    (new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "accessId")))
//                .setEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com", "us-west-1"))

                .enablePathStyleAccess()
                .disableChunkedEncoding()                
                 .build();  
 s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "key", convFile));
```

I tried two methodologies.

1) Converting Multipart file to java.io.File and uploading

```
Error: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: MyImage.png (No such file or directory)
```

2) Sending the image as bytestream

```
Error: I am getting java.io.FileNotFound Exception: /path/to/tomcat/MyImage.tmp not found
```

The actual image name is MyImage.png.

Either method I try, I get exception.

Comment: Could you not simply use putObject() with a File object, as shown at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Comment: @jarmod  AmazonS3Client is deprecated in the mentioned aws jdk.

Comment: Apologies for the obvious question, but does the local file exist in the stated location and is readable? If you remove the AWS SDK from the picture and try to open the same file from a simple Java app, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. There were several issues.

1. I mis typed the Region for a different set of keys.

But still the issues was happening and I went back to 1.11.76 version. And still there were some issues and this is how I fixed.

```
            ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            objectMetadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            byte[] contentBytes = null;
            try {
              InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
              contentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.err.printf("Failed while reading bytes from %s", e.getMessage());
            } 

          Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);
          objectMetadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
          objectMetadata.setHeader("filename", fileNameWithExtn);

          /*
           * Reobtain the tmp uploaded file as input stream
           */
          InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

          File convFile = new File(fileNameWithExtn); //If i don't do //this, I think I was getting file not found or MD5 error.
          file.transferTo(convFile); 

          FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, convFile);  //you //need to have commons.io in your pom.xml for this FileUtils to work. Not //the apache FileUtils. 
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
                    (new BasicAWSCredentials("<yourkeyId>", "<YourAccessKey>")));        
            s3.setRegion(Region.US_West.toAWSRegion());   
            s3.setEndpoint("yourRegion.amazonaws.com"); 
            versionId = s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("YourBucketName", name, convFile)).getVersionId();
```